# moving all of the columns in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have been working with Crystal Reports and one of the biggest issues I run into is that when I need to add a new column I have to move and resize each column proceeding where I put that new column. Is there any way to move all of the columns over at once? 
I've tried moving the guideline for the columns, but when I move the guideline to move over one column, it resizes the next column, rather than pushing it down the line. 
ex. Lets say I want to make Test Column1 bigger without making Test Column2 and Test Column3 smaller:

```
 | Test Column1 | Test Column2 | Test Column3 |
```

If I try and move the guideline to the right of Test Column1 to make it    bigger, it makes Test Column2 smaller as opposed to pushing it farther to the right and I get something like:

```
 | Test Column1        |Column2 | Test Column3 |
```

But what I want is:

```
 | Test Column1        | Test Column2 | Test Column3 |
```

I'm not sure if I'm explaining this well, if there is anything I can clarify let me know.

Comment: you mean... in design time? using the designer?

Comment: Yep, in the Design View

Comment: you could select the columns "test colum2" and "test column3" by clicking and draging the mouse, then move them to the right all together using the keyboard or the mouse, but probably you already know that, right?

Comment: Nope, didn't even think to try that. I was trying all these complicated things, and the solution is the simplest thing possible; funny how things like that happen.

do you know if there is any way to get the guidelines to move along with the arrow? it's pretty minor, but i'm just curious. Also, could you post this as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: Nickknack, I am not sure what are the "guidelines". If you mean resize the field at the same time, i think there is no way.

Comment: Guidelines are the things that keep all of the contents in different fields lined up; here is the link to the crystal reports page description: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-21721

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could select the columns "test colum2" and "test column3" by clicking and draging the mouse, then move them to the right all together using the keyboard or the mouse